# How to trigger Google Maps Weather Layer marker click?

Tags: google-maps, weather

I am trying to trigger a click on the Weather Layer of a google maps instance in order to open the weather info window of a city:

```
//Create the map
var options = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.265984,-123.127491),
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

//Create the weather layer
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer();
weatherLayer.setMap(map);

//Create the event, how?
var event = ?;

//Trigger the click
google.maps.event.trigger(weatherLayer, 'click', event);
```

The problem is the event that I have to pass to the trigger function. It must be an instance of [WeatherMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherMouseEvent). This instance is created by the layer when the user clicks on one of its markers, and I don't know how to generate this event.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible. I got a [response from a Google Employee](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/mWtrWktyCsU/9OydYX7V7XUJ):

> Unfortunately, it isn't possible to programmatically open a weather
>   layer info window. If you'd like to see this in the API, please file a
>   feature request: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list
>
> Enoch

I created a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4254).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var wEvent = google.maps.event.addListener(weatherLayer, 'click', myWeatherClick);

function myWeatherClick(wme) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(wme.latLng);
    infoWindow.setContent(wme.infoWindowHtml);
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Trigger the event:

```
var wme = {
        latLng: map.getCenter(),
        infoWindowHtml:'I\'ve been clicked'
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(weatherLayer, 'click', wme);
```

Comment: Thanks!

Can you please explain this code? What I have understood is that you are cloning the info window that is displayed when you click a marker of the weather layer.

Also I noticed that you are saving the return of the `addListener` method into `wEvent`. I inspected it and it is an object but I don't know what its purpose is.

And, finally, how can I trigger the click event?

Comment: I'm not "cloning" the infoWindow. An InfoWindow is an object that you need to instantiate. The wEvent variable is used if you want to remove the event listener. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Comment: Ok, thanks! Then, how can I use this code to trigger the click event?

Comment: To trigger the event you need to send a WeatherMouseEvent to the event handler. I've edited the reply to include it.

Comment: Additionally, to avoid duplicate infoWindows you could instantiate the weather layer with: var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({suppressInfoWindows:true});

Comment: I think I have not explained properly. What I need is to show the original info windows of the weather layer. With the example you propose you are creating custom info windows.

In other words, I need to trigger the click event without having to create the WeatherMouseEvent :)